# Mapping a curried filter using lodash functions

Tags: javascript, dictionary, filter, lodash, currying

I want to make a function that, given a list of predicates, produces an array filter.

Using lodash, I define:

```
const { curryRight, filter, flowRight } = require('lodash');

const curriedFilter = curryRight(filter);
const filterFromPredicates = (predicateList) => flowRight(...predicateList.map(curriedFilter));
```

But this gives the wrong answer:

```
const filter = filterFromPredicates([(x) => x > 2, (x) => x > 4])
filter([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]) // -> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

where I would expect `[5,6,7,8,9]`

However defining the curried filter as follows works:

```
const curriedFilter = (predicate) => (array) => array.filter(predicate);
```

Am I misunderstanding the usage of `curryRight`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because the map passes 3 arguments to the `curriedFilter` - the predicate, the index, and the original array. You'll need to pass only the predicate to `curriedFilter`.

```js
const { curryRight, filter, flow, ary } = _;

const curriedFilter = ary(curryRight(filter), 1);

const filterFromPredicates = (predicateList) => flow(...predicateList.map(curriedFilter)); // limit the number of params passed to curriedFilter

const fn = filterFromPredicates([x => x > 2, x => x < 6]); // don't override the filter you've imported

const result = fn([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]); // -> [3, 4, 5]

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Another option would be to limit the number of parameters `curriedFilter` accepts with `_.ary()`:

```js
const { curryRight, filter, flow, ary } = _;

const curriedFilter = ary(curryRight(filter), 1);

const filterFromPredicates = (predicateList) => flow(...predicateList.map(curriedFilter)); // limit the number of params passed to curriedFilter

const fn = filterFromPredicates([x => x > 2, x => x < 6]); // don't override the filter you've imported

const result = fn([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]); // -> [3, 4, 5]

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

You can use `_.overEvery()` to generate the predicate you'll pass to the curried filter:

```js
const { flow, overEvery, curryRight, filter } = _;

const filterFromPredicates = flow(overEvery, curryRight(filter));

const fn = filterFromPredicates(x => x > 2, x => x < 6); // don't override the filter you've imported

const result = fn([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]); // -> [3, 4, 5]

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

If you use lodash/fp you want need the `_.curryRight()` since the functions are auto-curried, and the parameters are iteratee-first data-last:

```js
const { flow, overEvery, filter } = _;

const filterFromPredicates = flow(overEvery, filter);

const fn = filterFromPredicates([x => x > 2, x => x < 6]); // don't override the filter you've imported

const result = fn([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]); // -> [3, 4, 5]

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Comment: Nice! But what I'm wondering is why the first version doesn't work (I also show another working implementation in the OP)

Comment: Just beat me to it.  I was initially surprised because I thought the Ramda equivalent (`(predicates) => compose(...map(filter, predicates))` or `compose(apply(compose), map(filter))`)
 would simply work.  It does, but if you used `Array.prototype.map`, it would have the same issue.

Comment: @ScottSauyet - yep. That's what true me of the track as well. Besides playing with Ramda, I usually use lodash/fp, and the number of parameters passed to the predicate are limited as well.

Comment: (Of course the real Ramda equivalent is the built-in [`allPass`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#allPass).  But that's a separate story.)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
function filterFromPredicates(predicates) {
 return (...args) => predicates
  .map(predfn=> predfn(...args))
  .every(a=>a)
}
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].filter(filterFromPredicates([(x) => x > 2, (x) => x > 4]))
```

if you want everything in the same function then :

```
function filterFromPredicates(predicates) {
     return (someArray)=> someArray.filter((...args) => predicates
      .map(predfn=> predfn(...args))
      .every(a=>a))
    }

const filter = filterFromPredicates([(x) => x > 2, (x) => x > 4])
filter([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
```

That will return as you wanted ^

Comment: Nice! But what I'm wondering is why the lodash version doesn't work (I also show another working implementation in the OP)